# RabbitMQ cluster connection using MassTransit gives BrokerUnreachableException

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm having the exact same problem this guy is having: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/975.

For testing purposes, I have a 3 node cluster on my dev machine, following ports are used by the nodes:

```
amqp rabbit 5672
http rabbit 15672

amqp rabbit1 6001
http rabbit1 15674

amqp rabbit2 6002
http rabbit2 15673
```

And I try to connect as follows:

```
var rabbitMqHost = busFactoryConfig.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost:6002"), hostConfig =>
{
  hostConfig.Username("username");
  hostConfig.Password("password");
  hostConfig.UseCluster(c =>
  {
    c.ClusterMembers = new[]
    {
      "rabbitmq://localhost:6001",
      "rabbitmq://localhost:6002",
      "rabbitmq://localhost:5672"
    };
  });
});
```

But I keep getting:

> Connect failed: admin@localhost:6002/
>
> BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tried every possibility, nothing works. If I remove `UseCluster` then same host:port works which is weird.

Using the clustername as hostname (like this: `busFactoryConfig.Host("rabbit2@{hostname-fqdn}", "/", ...`) gives the following error:

> EndpointNotFoundException: The host was not found for the specified address: rabbitmq://rabbit2@{hostname-fqdn}/bus-{hostname}-RabbitMQConsumer-rnuoyyrtr44jcxutbdmpkkikdu?durable=false&autodelete=true

RabbitMQ v3.7.14, Erlang v21.3

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got it.

Try this after create rabbitMqHost

```
var rabbitMqHost = busFactoryConfig.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://rabbit2/"), hostConfig =>
{
    hostConfig.Username("username");
    hostConfig.Password("password");
    hostConfig.UseCluster(c =>
    {
        c.Node("rabbit");
        c.Node("rabbit1");
        c.Node("rabbit2");
    });
});

rabbitMqHost.Settings.GetConnectionFactory().Endpoint.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my problem after 1000 tries, as follows:

```
var rabbitMqHost = busFactoryConfig.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://rabbit2/"), hostConfig =>
{
    hostConfig.Username("username");
    hostConfig.Password("password");
    hostConfig.UseCluster(c =>
    {
        c.Node("rabbit");
        c.Node("rabbit1");
        c.Node("rabbit2");
    });
});
```

And I added following to the hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1 rabbit2
```

But it still messes with the ports (because all nodes are localhost)... So still no success.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the AddressFamily property on CreateConnection.

```
 var factory = new RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory
{
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password"
};
var conn  = factory.CreateConnection(new [] { new AmqpTcpEndpoint("hostname") {AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork}});
```

Comment: ty for your answer, but I wanted to know a way with `MassTransit`